# Async function cast a "One or more errors occurred" error

Tags: c#, exception

I need help to understand this issue.

I get this exception:

> ```
> One or more errors occurred.
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
> ```

This is my calling function:

```cs
var dtReimb2 = new Schemas.ReimbursementFactorsSchema.ReimbursementFactorsDataTable();
var oReimbursementFactors = Task.Run(async () => await ClientApi.GetReimbursementsFactorsAsync(custNo));
    if (oReimbursementFactors.Result.LabourReimbursement.Count > 0) // Cast Error here
    {
        foreach (var reimbursementItem in oReimbursementFactors.Result.LabourReimbursement)
        {
            // New row
```

`ClientApi.GetReimbursementsFactorsAsync` function:

```
internal static async Task<LabourReimbursements> GetReimbursementsFactorsAsync(string custNo)
{
    try
    {
        var token = await GetTokenAsync();

        if(token.AccessToken == null)
        {
            CommonFunctions.WriteToEventLog(System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Warning, "Token AccessToken null. ");
        }
    
        string LabourReimbursementsJson;

        var data = new
        {
            CustomerNumber = custNo,
            Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        };

        if (token.AccessToken != null)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                //CommonFunctions.WriteToEventLog(System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information, "RestApi Init: ");

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = await GetResponseMessageAsync(token, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), httpClient, "getCustomerPriceList");

                    if (ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        LabourReimbursementsJson = await ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //CommonFunctions.WriteToEventLog(System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information, "RestApi Response: " + LabourReimbursementsJson.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Call to GetReimbursementsFactorsAsync failed: " + ResponseMessage.StatusCode);
                    }

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabourReimbursements>(LabourReimbursementsJson);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    CommonFunctions.WriteToEventLog(System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "RestApi Request Error: No Connection. " + e.Message);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        CommonFunctions.WriteToEventLog(System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "ClientApi GetReimbu..Async Error: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

`GetTokenAsync` function:

```
public static async Task<Token> GetTokenAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await _tokenSemaphore.WaitAsync();

        if (_token.Expired == false)
        {
            return _token;
        }

        _token = await GetAccessTokenAsync();

        return _token;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        CommonFunctions.WriteToEventLog(System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error, "ClientApi GetTokenAsync Error: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        _tokenSemaphore.Release(1);
    }
}
```

`GetResponseMessageAsync` function:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessageAsync(Token token, string data2, HttpClient httpClient, string method)
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.TokenType, token.AccessToken);
    
    try
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(endPoint + method);

        StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(data2);

        var ResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(endPoint + method, httpContent);

        return ResponseMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
        //throw;
    }
}
```

Why do I get this exception?

Comment: Look at the inner exception. You exception is currently wrapped so the inner exception should give you a clearer picture of what is going wrong in your code

Comment: It's the only exception I get actually, how can I find the inner exception?

Comment: Look at the `InnerException` property of your exception.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this issue happens in the production server and I can not replicate it in my development environment.

Comment: I forgot to say that this problem appears when the server's activity is high, it doesn't happen all the time

Comment: Then extend logging so that the inner exception is also logged so you get something to work with.

Comment: Also when logging as this is presumably an AggregateException not only look at  `InnerException` but also at the `InnerExceptions` list and log them.

Comment: Great, thanks you, can you show how can I do that in my code please?